# What does 'adb shell start/stop' do?

Tags: android, adb

## Question

What do `adb shell start` and `adb shell stop` actually do?

## Description

I think they call `/system/bin/start` and `/system/bin/stop`. But these two executables don't give any clue about what they do. When tested on a real device, I found the zygote process is started and stopped. So these two commands seem to control the Android runtime (which corresponds to the yellow and blue parts in the figure below).

[image: Android Architecture]

But **what exact processes/services** are started/stopped with these two commands?

Comment: source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/brillo-m8-release/toolbox/start_stop.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this on your device

```
grep ^service /init*rc
```

Comment: Until quite recently, most official android releases did not include `grep`

Comment: Use `adb pull` to copy all those files onto your workstation and then run grep from there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: compile/download `busybox` and run `busybox grep`.

Comment: @pevik - you might notice my comment said "until recently" and was written in 2013.  Most Android devices in use today have a built in grep.  Busybox is an option for those that don't, but it can be a pain to install for convenient use on secured devices.  Examining the init files on a development machine is probably going to be more informative anyway, but now that it is there I do use the built in grep if I have a strong idea of what I am looking for.

Comment: How does this address the question??

Comment: @DonHatch after you do the grep command you will get list of available services. start/stop would allow you to start/stop these services

Answer (score 22):

Basically, all your Android services are restarted; those that are created and registered in `SystemServer.java`. This is called within the "Context of Zygote". So yes, Zygote is stopped.

All your services registered with `ServiceManager` in Android will get removed within `ServiceManager`. To restart them, do `adb shell start`.

Also note that `SystemServer` is started by Zygote, so `init.rc` tells that if Zygote is stopped, then even `SystemServer` must be stopped. Even `SurfaceFlinger` dies, since it's started from `SystemServer` but natively.

Answer (score 2):

I have been wondering what "stop" does on Android too. Learned from someone that "stop" stops AP being rendered by SurfaceFlinger.

Had a try with the command like below. Execute the command, wait for a few seconds and then execute "stop" on Android. The command keeps printing increased number and creating .txt files. So maybe it only stops the Android part while the Linux part remains active. Just FYI.

```
busybox sh -c 'i=0;while [ $i -ne 100 ]; do echo $i >> count.txt; sleep 1; i=$(($i + 1)); echo $i; touch "$i.txt"; done;'
```

Answer (score 2):

**adb shell "start --help"**

usage: start [SERVICE...]

Starts the given system service, or netd/surfaceflinger/zygotes.

**adb shell "stop --help"**

usage: stop [SERVICE...]

Stops the given system service, or netd/surfaceflinger/zygotes.