# Android Room Database DAO debug log

Tags: android, logging, android-room

Given a Room database DAO like this:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface MyDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
    List<MyItem> all();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE date = :date AND language = :language")
    MyItem byDate(Date date, String language);


}
```

Is there a way to have a Logger or something like that added to `MyDao` so that I could see which statements are being performed. This would be really helpful during development, because I could immediately check if the functions are transformed correctly to the expected SQL statement or not.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @MehulJoisar I have posted my answer below, it worked for me. Might help you out.

Answer (score 59):

Assuming that Room uses framework's Sqlite as underlying database, the statements can be quite simply logged. The only limitation: this can be done only on **emulator**.

From [SQLiteDebug.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/33f921769531968a3ba9bc73fb2410f95868cb8d/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDebug.java#L52L58):

> ```
> /**
>  * Controls the printing of SQL statements as they are executed.
>  *
>  * Enable using "adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements VERBOSE".
>  */
> public static final boolean DEBUG_SQL_STATEMENTS =
>         Log.isLoggable("SQLiteStatements", Log.VERBOSE);
> ```

---

By default, the `log.tag.SQLiteStatements`'s value is not set:

> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell getprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements**
> <-- BLANK LINE -->

According to the above documentation, to set the property we have to use:

> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements VERBOSE**
> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell getprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements**
> VERBOSE

As we can see, the `VERBOSE` value was successfully set. However, if we'll re-run our application - we won't see those statements printed. To make it work, we'll have to [restart all the services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17278099/1233652) using `adb shell stop` and then `adb shell start`.
If you'll try to do that with a regular device, you'll receive the following error (tried with Pixel XL / stock Android 9):

> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell start**
> start: must be root
> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb root**
> adbd cannot run as root in production builds

This is why we have to use the emulator:

> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb root**
> restarting adbd as root
> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell stop**
> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell start**

The emulator will restart.
Run your application and you'll see similar Sqlite statements in logcat:

```
<redacted..>
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;"
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)"
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, "3cb5664b6da264c13388292d98141843")"
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (`id` TEXT NOT NULL, `date` INTEGER, `language` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))"
<redacted..>
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;"
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;"
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "PRAGMA recursive_triggers='ON';"
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "CREATE TEMP TABLE room_table_modification_log(version INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, table_id INTEGER)"
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "COMMIT;"
<redacted..>
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
V/SQLiteStatements: <redacted>/my_db: "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE date = 1551562171387 AND language = 'en'"
```

---

To undo the changes, use these commands:

> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements ""**
> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell getprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements**
> <-- BLANK LINE -->
> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell stop**
> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb shell start**
> alex@mbpro:~$ **adb unroot**
> restarting adbd as non root

Comment: This was extremely helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: The boolean method you put at the start of your answer. Where does this code go?

Comment: @AndroidDev123 I guess you're referring to `DEBUG_SQL_STATEMENTS`. You don't call it directly (framework does), I've added it just as a reference to the comment written above it.

Comment: Im struggling to follow your answer. What exactly are we supposed to do to see the print out of the query in the log? I dont understand what all this $adb shell commands are about and where does this even go in android studio?

Comment: @AndroidDev123 The above steps don't require any code changes. Everything is done using `adb` command-line tool, which is bundled in Android SDK, and can be invoked from the terminal (you can find exact details in [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)).

Comment: I've progressed this to adb root which now returns it canot be root in production builds. How do you gain root access on the emulator?

Comment: @AndroidDev123 You should use an AOSP system image that allows elevated privileges, as per [this description](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#system-image).

Comment: It appears to be working as I can see all the queries in the logcat but what I really wanted to see was the output of the query like column names with the data in the rows - just seeing the query doesnt help as I mean its just the same query I wrote in the DAO

Comment: This is great. Exactly what I was looking for. I can now debug all database operations with precision! Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 41):

As of [Room 2.3.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.3.0-alpha04) (released December 16 2020, could be stable by the time you're reading this), there's direct support in Room for logging SQL queries with the new `RoomDatabase.QueryCallback`

You set this callback on the `RoomDatabase.Builder`

```
    fun getDatabase(context: Context): MyDatabase {
        val dbBuilder = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            MyDatabase::class.java, "mydatabase.db"
        )
        dbBuilder.setQueryCallback(RoomDatabase.QueryCallback { sqlQuery, bindArgs ->
            println("SQL Query: $sqlQuery SQL Args: $bindArgs")
        }, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
        return dbBuilder.build()
    }
```

Note this is just example code and you should probably ensure `MyDatabase` is a singleton in your app. Another tip is only log queries when the app is DEBUG:
`if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) dbBuilder.setQueryCallback(`... and the rest of the code from above.

Comment if anybody wants the example code in Java

Comment: In case you decide to use Log.xxx method, keep in mind, that there's a max char length limit for the message. So if you are missing some of the queries in your Logcat, try to split the sqlQuery into multiple log entries. (some examples are here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888654/android-set-max-length-of-logcat-messages])

Comment: It's in stable release `2.3.0` now [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_230_3].

Comment: @georgiecasey, could you please help to share the Java code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @georgiecasey, I've been able to make it work with Java code. But looks it's all placeholders "?" in the SQL. Is there anyway to display the actually executed SQL? The "?" has to be specific value.

Answer (score 21):

As per [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) of Room it performs compile time check so if your SQL statement is not valid compilation itself failed and proper error message is displayed in the log.

Also generated code is debuggable by default and can be found under below mentioned path.

> build > generated > source > apt > your Package > yourDao_Impl.java

This class contains implementation of your DAO you can debug this class as you debug other classes in your project. :-)

Example :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw that `_Impl` myself while debugging but I couldn't find a full string where all the placeholders are already filled with the arguments. Maybe I missed it?

Comment: @IHeartAndroid Have you found any solution which provides logs ?

Answer (score 19):

There does not appear to be any hooks for that at the DAO level. There are callbacks related to database opens and upgrades, but not arbitrary stuff.

You could [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:197448), though. I agree that it could be useful. Even better would be an OkHttp-style generic interceptor framework.

Comment: Since there didn't seem to be any other feature request:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74877608

Comment: it seems the feature is still not implemented. Any other workaround to get logs?

Comment: @MehulJoisar: Yiğit had an interesting angle in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74877608#comment4, which is to write a series of support database classes that would handle the logging. I do not know of anyone who has done that for logging, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I use that in my application? please share some thoughts.

Comment: @MehulJoisar: Instructions for how to create a custom set of support database API classes is well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, let alone a comment. In a nutshell, you need to create implementations of several interfaces (e.g., `SupportSQLiteDatabase`), wire them together, and have a `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory` to be able to apply them to a `RoomDatabase.Builder`. I do this in [CWAC-SafeRoom](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom), in my case to support SQLCipher.

Comment: @MehulJoisar: In [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.11/General/AssetRoom), I have a subset of those interfaces, just enough to wrap the supplied support database API, to allow you to package a database as an asset. A logging set of support database classes would resemble the latter, passing through the real work to another implementation of the support database classes, but also doing some logging.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for sharing the information. It seems lot of customisation will need to be made just to inject a middleware for logging. I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

When I have got some unknown error while inserting or updating row in room db Android does not show any error in debug console. One thing I found how to check whats happen while debug is:

```
try { someSource.update(someRow) } catch (e: Throwable) { println(e.message) }
```

Output is:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: quiz.theme (code 2067)

Comment: In which place? ViewModel / Repo etc !!

Comment: @Abhiroop Nandi Ray, It's only for debug, in place where you want. If you use this code: try { yourDao.getAllRowsFromDB() } catch ... and get some exception it'll be caught in catch block.

Comment: Nice approach, saved my day!

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to achieve it via a hack for Select queries. This wont work for insert/update/delete operations :)

Create a separate class `RoomLoggingHelper` as follows

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.room.RoomSQLiteQuery

private const val NULL = 1
private const val LONG = 2
private const val DOUBLE = 3
private const val STRING = 4
private const val BLOB = 5
private const val NULL_QUERY = "NULL"

const val ROOM_LOGGING_TAG = "roomQueryLog"

object RoomLoggingHelper {

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    fun getStringSql(query: RoomSQLiteQuery): String {
        val argList = arrayListOf<String>()
        val bindingTypes = query.getBindingTypes()
        var i = 0

        while (i < bindingTypes.size) {
            val bindingType = bindingTypes[i]

            when (bindingType) {
                NULL -> argList.add(NULL_QUERY)
                LONG -> argList.add(query.getLongBindings()[i].toString())
                DOUBLE -> argList.add(query.getDoubleBindings()[i].toString())
                STRING -> argList.add(query.getStringBindings()[i].toString())
            }
            i++
        }

        return String.format(query.sql.replace("?", "%s"), *argList.toArray())
    }

    fun getStringSql(query: String?, args: Array<out Any>?): String? {
        return if (query != null && args != null) {
            String.format(query.replace("?", "%s"), *args)
        } else
            ""
    }
}

private fun RoomSQLiteQuery.getBindingTypes(): IntArray {

    return javaClass.getDeclaredField("mBindingTypes").let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return@let field.get(this) as IntArray
    }
}

private fun RoomSQLiteQuery.getLongBindings(): LongArray {

    return javaClass.getDeclaredField("mLongBindings").let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return@let field.get(this) as LongArray
    }
}

private fun RoomSQLiteQuery.getStringBindings(): Array<String> {

    return javaClass.getDeclaredField("mStringBindings").let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return@let field.get(this) as Array<String>
    }
}

private fun RoomSQLiteQuery.getDoubleBindings(): DoubleArray {

    return javaClass.getDeclaredField("mDoubleBindings").let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return@let field.get(this) as DoubleArray
    }
}

private fun RoomSQLiteQuery.getIntBindings(): IntArray {

    return javaClass.getDeclaredField("mBindingTypes").let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        return@let field.get(this) as IntArray
    }
}
```

Or, you can download this file from [here](https://gist.github.com/aasaandinesh/6e4cf206bd1bb56966954cabc42128dd)

Add this file to your Project and call it from your Room Database class as follows:
 Override both the `query` methods like this

```
override fun query(query: SupportSQLiteQuery?): Cursor {
        //This will give you the SQL String
        val queryString = RoomLoggingHelper.getStringSql(query as RoomSQLiteQuery)
        //You can log it in a way you like, I am using Timber
        Timber.d("$ROOM_LOGGING_TAG $queryString")
        return super.query(query)
    }

    override fun query(query: String?, args: Array<out Any>?): Cursor {
        //This will give you the SQL String
        val queryString = RoomLoggingHelper.getStringSql(query, args)
        //You can log it in a way you like, I am using Timber
        Timber.d("$ROOM_LOGGING_TAG $queryString")
        return super.query(query, args)
    }
```

Disclaimers:

- I am using Reflection to get string SQL, hence **use this ONLY in DEBUG mode**
- This is written in haste and may contain errors, it would be wise to keep it in `try-catch` block
- Also, I have tested it for string args, should work for long and double as well, will not work for `Blobs`

Comment: I will check it out, will it be working on production also?

Comment: @MehulJoisar You should only use this in debug build, not in the production build because I am using reflection, it may affect the performance. You can follow this link for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844667/how-do-i-detect-if-i-am-in-release-or-debug-mode

Comment: I am using @DineshSingh code example, however I've problems with my custom queries, so I've made the following changes: `if (argList.size == 0) return; query.sql

        var sql = query.sql

        argList.forEach{
            sql = sql.replaceFirst("?", it)
        }

        return sql` instead of `return String.format(query.sql.replace("?", "%s"), *argList.toArray())`. To know if you're in `Debug Mode`, you can use the following statement: `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { val queryString = RoomLoggingHelper.getStringSql(query, args) Log.d("Room", queryString) } return super.query(query)`