# How to print the internal query in a Room database?

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

How to print query in `Room` ? Not the query written in dao but the query generated by room itself.

Comment: At this time Room doesn't have any logging policy itself

Comment: You can log Room's Sqlite statements on emulator, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963655/1233652

Answer (score 5):

For every **DAO** class you add to your project **marked** with `@Dao` Room **generate** a class that implement your class. Hence for operations like Insert, Update and Delete that you don't provide any query Room will create a query itself. You can see this generated classes in the following file inside your project:

```
{root project}/app/build/generated/source/apt
```

, now navigate to the package that contains DAO classes and you will see classes like `IssueDao_Impl.java`. Inside this class you will see queries like this:

```
"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO `Issue`(`id`,`displayOrder`,`pdf`,`date`,`purchasable`,`source_id`,`thumb`,`full`,`mobile`,`width`,`height`,`download_count`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

, created with the help of the **annotations** you did inside your class. Cheers!